# Django: Get page title from middleware

Tags: python, django, dom, django-middleware

I have a small middleware I wrote to keep track of user activity:

```
class AccessLogs(object):

def __init__(self, get_response):
    self.get_response = get_response

def __call__(self, request):
    response = self.get_response(request)

    if "/media/" not in request.path:
        try:
            ActivityLog(user=request.user, pageURL=request.path).save()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    return response
```

Is there any way I can get the title of the page using this method of middleware? I have looked up a LOT of stuff here like templateview, custom response but nothing seems to be working. Is there any class or function that retrieves the visited page's title? Any help would be really appreciated.

EDIT: What I'm trying to look for is a method to get the title of the page user has just visited, so I can store it with other information in the database with it in this middleware.

Comment: Is the title of the page an attribute on the view? Can you show an example view that you want to get the title of?

Comment: @IainShelvington: I think it is the `<title>...</title>` tag in the response.

Comment: `request.resolver_match.view_name` will contain the name of the view set in the path/url. If that is enough I would suggest using that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, although not all responses are HTTP responses, nor do all HTTP responses have *per se* a title. But we can try to do a best effort to obtain the title from the response.

In order to do this, we can use a HTML scraper, like [**`beautifulsoup4`** [PiPy]](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/). You might need to install:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4 lxml
```

We can then aim to obtain the title from a response with:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_response_title(response):
    try:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
        return soup.find('title').getText()
    except AttributeError:
        return None
```

You can thus use this in your middleware like:

```
class AccessLogs(object):

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        if '/media/' not in request.path:
            try:
                title = get_response_title(response)
                ActivityLog(user=request.user, title=title, pageURL=request.path).save()
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
```

That being said, as [@IainShelvington says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56921999/django-get-page-title-from-middleware/56922064?noredirect=1#comment100386456_56922064), it will slow down processing, since we each time will take a look at the response. Some web development frameworks like [*Yesod* [yesodweb.com]](https://www.yesodweb.com/) will set the title as a variable that is passed in the handler, and thus make it more convenient to detect that.

Comment: Just to add to this, you probably should not do this if you care about performance. Parsing every response just to get the title is a bit overkill.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid html scrapping, but for now I will work with this. Thank you so much!

Comment: @IainShelvington: well it is indeed a bit overkill, I agree on that. It is a bit sad, that Django does not have a handler object, that is designed to collect the title, and then render it, like for example the Handler Widget monad of Yesod.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I agree, to handle this properly in Django you would probably have to create another "framework" or a Mixin that was added to every view on the top of Django that added that title to every response but that is a lot of boilerplate